# Implement the stored procedure iterative approach in a SQL manner

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, convolution

I am trying to implement convolution between two vectors v1 and v2. As part of that I have written a stored procedure with an iterative approach using while loops. Here is the below code as below. I am not able to think through how to do it using SQL as the stored procedure is inefficient w.r.t performance. Can somebody share your thoughts on this? Any inputs would be appreciated.

Idea behind writing the stored procedure:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/ipp-dev-reference-convolve

[image]

Table schema and sample input data:

```
CREATE TABLE AIRWork..TableA (idx INT, val INT);

CREATE TABLE AIRWork..TableB (idx INT, val INT);

INSERT INTO AIRWork..TableA 
VALUES (0, -2), (1, 0), (2, 1), (3, -1), (4, 3);

INSERT INTO AIRWork..TableB 
VALUES (0, 0), (1, 1);
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Calc_Convolved_Values_Test  
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @srclen1 INT 
    DECLARE @srclen2 INT 
    DECLARE @n INT = 0
    DECLARE @k INT
    DECLARE @m INT
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000)
    DECLARE @x int
    DECLARE @xx int = 0
    DECLARE @sum INT = 0
    DECLARE @y int
    DECLARE @yy int = 0
    DECLARE @a INT = 0
    DECLARE @b INT = 0

    SELECT @srclen1 = COUNT(*) FROM AIRWork..TableA;

    SELECT @srclen2 = COUNT(*) FROM AIRWork..TableB;

    SET @m = @srclen1 + @srclen2 -1

    WHILE @n < @m
    BEGIN
            SET @k = 0
            SET @sum = 0
            WHILE @k <= @n
            BEGIN 

                      SET @SQL = 'SELECT @x=val FROM AIRWork..TableA WHERE idx ='+CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),@k)

                      EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@x int out', @xx out

                      SET @a = @xx

                      IF @n-@k < @srclen2
                      BEGIN
                            SET @SQL = 'SELECT @y=val FROM AIRWork..TableB WHERE idx ='+CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),@n-@k)

                            EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@y int out', @yy out

                            SET @b = @yy
                      END
                      ELSE 
                      BEGIN
                            SET @b = 0
                      END 

                      SET @sum = @sum + @a*@b

                      SET @k = @k + 1
            END 
            PRINT @sum 
            SET @n = @n + 1 
    END


END
GO
```

Sample output:

pDst[n] --> Please check the formula in the beginning of the question.

```
    0
   -2
    0
    1
   -1
    3
```

Comment: What is the datatype of the `val` and `idx` columns?

Comment: int is the data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This procedure should do it:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Calc_Convolved_Values_Test  
AS

    ;WITH AllRows AS 
    (
                SELECT idx, val, 0 as tbl FROM AIRWork..TableA
      UNION ALL SELECT idx, val, 1 as tbl FROM AIRWork..TableB
    )
    , CombinedRows As
    (
        SELECT  *, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY tbl, idx)-1 As k,
                COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY 1) - 1      As n
        FROM AllRows
    )
    SELECT  ABDest.k As idx,  SUM(A.val * B.val) As val
    FROM    CombinedRows AS ABDest
    JOIN    CombinedRows AS AB          ON AB.k <= ABDest.k
    LEFT JOIN   AIRWork..TableA As A    ON A.idx = AB.k
    LEFT JOIN   AIRWork..TableB As B    ON B.idx = ABDest.k - AB.k
    WHERE ABDest.k < ABDest.n
    GROUP BY ABDest.k
    ORDER BY ABDest.k

GO
```

FYI, I would not recommend using a whole table to store a single vector.  You would be much better off storing all of your vectors in the same table and using a name or ID key column to separate them.